# Friendly URLs with several parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying many different examples I browsed on this forum and other websites to create the urls more user friendly with no success. I'll try my luck with all of you experts here.

I've got a structure of my url that looks like this:

> index.php?mod=post&id=10

The mod parameter can contain an array of different keys, each one will include a defined module to the template.

I was hoping to achieve something similar to:

> my-url.com/post/10

At the moment I am only interessted to change the url when the value of `mod` equals to `post`.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Use a proper routing system, instead of  unmaintainable .htaccess hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your public_html/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?mod=([^&]+)&id=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mod=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Worht to mention: At my server I have many projects.. the structure I've got is something like public_html/index.php (testing and for my own reference),project1[folder], project2[folder], project3[folder]. Each folder is a different project. Using your code will forward me to my phpinfo file in the root instead of the actual blogpost in project3. Suggestions? Thanks for helping out. Much appriciated.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it.. like this:  `RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ /project3/index.php?mod=post&id=$2 [QSA,L,NC] `. Going to do some testing. I'll let you know.

Comment: Nope.. didn't work. All links are affected this way `post/10/?mod=home` now. I'm clueless.

Comment: It keeps showing the links like this `post/10/?mod=home` and all images are gone :) Thanks for giving it a shot though. Much appriciated.